# How to force focus on a NumberPicker (android)?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have two questions:

**First**, is there a way to focus on the NumberPicker without clicking on it (with Java code)?

- `np.requestFocus()` doesn't work.

**Second**, is there a way to increase the speed between changing one number and the next (always in the NumberPicker), since it is quite slow?

*My NumberPicker xml:*

```
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/dmx_picker"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/NumberPicker" />
```

*Java variable:*

```
NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.dmx_picker);
```

Thanks, have a good day.